# Canon i-SENSYS MF4330d

Tags: canon

I have got a Canon i-SENSYS MF4330d multi-functional laser (copy + printer + scanner).

I want to be able to print from (and scan to if possible) my Ubuntu 14.04 system.
How can I install it?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the Canon website, find [your product](http://www.canon.co.uk/for_home/product_finder/multifunctionals/laser/i-sensys_mf4330d/), click on the *Support and Download* button, and download the Linux drivers from [Canon i-SENSYS MF4320d - Drivers](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf4320d.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=WINDOWS%207%20(32-bit)). Use the drop down menu to select Linux (32 or 64 bit).

Here are the direct links:

- [32 bit Linux version](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf4320d.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(32-bit))
- [64 bit Linux version](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf4320d.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit))